# Ignoring Code Smell Violations in Sonar lint Visual Studio C#

Tags: visual-studio, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have installed Sonar Lint Extension for Visual Studio 2019 and according to the project i am working it is not required to fix the Code Smell Violations.

So is there a way that i can ignore the code smell violations using sonar lint in VS2019

please note that we are using sonar Lint in connected mode wit sonar cube server

Answer (score 0):

Connected mode is to designed to configure the IDE to use the same set of rules as are configured in your Quality Profile on the SonarQube server, so if the code smell rules are part of your Quality Profile then they will be enabled in the IDE too.

If you don't want to see those issues reported in the IDE then you could either remove those rules from the Quality Profile, or use standalone mode and configure the set of rules to run locally as described [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-visualstudio/wiki/Choosing-which-C%23-or-VB.NET-rules-to-run-in-Standalone-mode).

Answer (score 0):

After doing some tweaks in the visual studio I was able to add the column category to the sonar output window and in that filtered out the sonar issues other than code smells.